# unable to decode the string from database into JSON

Tags: php, json

I am storing a value in database with the help of `stringify` like

```
var value = JSON.stringify(credit);
```

and storing it in database through ajax.

**javascript** :

```
$(".revolving_credit_row").each(function(){
        var revolving_credit_object = {};
        var that  = $(this);

        that.find('.revolving_credit_input').each(function (){
            var field_name = $(this).attr('data-field-name');
            var field_value = $(this).val();

            revolving_credit_object[field_name] = field_value;
        });

        revolving_credit.push(revolving_credit_object);
    });

var value = JSON.stringify(revolving_credit);
```

Value in database is like

`[{"Creditor":"12500","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""},{"Creditor":"20525","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""},{"Creditor":"","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""}]`

Now as i am getting on retrieving it is giving me back exact string but i am unable to decode it.

i am using this function.

```
$credit = $business[0]->credit;

$temp = json_decode($credit);

        print_r($temp);
        exit;
```

as i `print_r` it does not give any output and if i use `var_export`, or `var_dump` it is giving me null.

Comment: your code is not enough to reproduce the problem. yould you add a `var_dump($credit)` for starters? and maybe the data retrieval logic?

Answer (score -1):

Must be:

```
$temp = '[{"Creditor":"12500","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""},{"Creditor":"20525","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""},{"Creditor":"","Balance":"","Limit":"","Utilization":""}]';

print_r($temp);

var_dump(json_decode($temp));
var_dump(json_decode($temp, true));
```

I you don't have this between '  ', will not works the function `json_decode()`.

Comment: how can i put them when i stringify them in the javascript.

Comment: Can I see what have you done with the javascript sentence? Have you do a JSON.stringfy(object) ?

Comment: Bu if it rise just like a array format, I think that you don't need give the stringfy with Javascript, you can take the json array and make a decode directly

Comment: how can i save that in the database if it is not stringify?

Comment: You can change the type field to json.